# Re-save all products in Magento2 - Weird error has forced me to manually resave products to get configurable options to show up on frontend

Tags: magento2, script

I can't find any information on how to programmatically re-save all products.

I'm running into a weird error that suddenly all products with configurable options, the options no longer show up on the frontend unless I manually go into the backend and click save on the product.

I have over 1000 products so it would be really helpful if I could get a script working to programatically re-save all products so that their options show up on the frontend again.

Things I have already tried:

1. reindex all by `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
2. cleared all cache etc
3. redeployed static assets
4. ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` etc...

If someone could convert this logic to Magento 2 that would be soooo helpful and save me probably 10 hours of work:

http://magetechno.com/wpmaster/resave-all-products-in-magento/

> "Due to index problem in Magento which causes the product information
>   isn’t shown correctly on frontend. You will have to resave the product
>   to have correct data again. But there are a lot of products you can do
>   it manually. Here is script to help you to save all products quickly.
>
> Step 1 : Create file named “resaveallproduct.php” in root folder of
>   magento. Step 2 : Paste following code."
>
> ```
> // require magento core
> require_once 'app/Mage.php';
>
> // execute on admin store
> Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
>
> $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
> foreach($products as $product) {
>     echo $product->getName() . '<br/>';
>     // save the product
>     $product->save();
> }
>
> echo 'Congratulations!!! Product resaved';
> ?>
> ```
>
> Step 3 : Now run “resaveallproduct.php” file from broswer. For Example
>   : yourdomain/resaveallproduct.php

I need the above code basically to work for magento 2, or any other type of workaround.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best would be to use an UpgradeData script. First, you will need to create a module - which is [pretty easy](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) (or see the example files below). You only need to create the `registration.php` and `etc/module.xml` files and then run:

- `bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Component_Name`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

After that, create an UpgradeData class in a setup directory. There you will need to use constructor dependency injection for the product collection and the state. After you have those in your class, setup the upgrade method to do the work.

*Note:* you will need to change the `setup_version` in your `module.xml` any time that you want the script to run.

Here's an example (in my test module `SwiftOtter\ShareButtons`):

```
namespace SwiftOtter\ShareButtons\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\{UpgradeDataInterface, ModuleDataSetupInterface, ModuleContextInterface};

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    protected $productCollection;
    protected $state;

    public function __construct(Collection $productCollection, State $state) {
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->state->setAreaCode('frontend');

        $products = $this->productCollection->load();
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($i > 4) {
                break;
            }

            $product->save();
            $i++;
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

A few notes on that:

1. That is using PHP7 for the `use` statements so you will need to adjust the curly braces if you are running 5.6.
2. I left the iterator in there so you could easily test just the first couple of products in your store to ensure it works correctly.

---

If it helps, here's what the `etc/module.xml` is (after you change the name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <module name="SwiftOtter_ShareButtons" setup_version="0.1.7" />
</config>
```

And `registration.php`:

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'SwiftOtter_ShareButtons', __DIR__);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$productCollection->load();

foreach($productCollection  as $product)
{

 ................

 ................

 ............ 

 $product->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is the following:

Create a new product attribute, attribute name and attribute code are irrelevant, just make sure it is **not** visible on the frontend.

Any time you want to re-save all products, go to Products -> Catalog grid, select **all** products and click on 'Update Attributes' from the Actions dropdown (top left of the grid).

Change the value for your new attribute and save. If this takes too long or if you run into timeouts you can also do this page-by-page. You can set the page size to any size you want (e.g. batches of 500).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `ProductRepository`:

```
$filters = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$products = $this->productRepository->getList($filters);

foreach ($products as $product) {
     echo $product->getName() . "\n";

     $this->productRepository->save($product);
}
```